# I want to push information to a running AngularJS page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

What I'm trying to do is have a webpage running on a rasberrypi and display that is showing a photo, a name, a title, and a current status. I already have the page running and can change those files in a local file that, when saved, does update the page without having to refresh it. However, I want to be able to change one or all of those items from a remote computer by pushing a file to my pi and without having to reload the page. I'm using angularJS and node.js in this project. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is too broad. Please give us some [more details and an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can help you with towards solving your question

Comment: Angular is a front-end framework, so it would have to know about the change. You would need some sort of pub/sub setup such as with RabbitMQ. A job would have to watch the directory/files, and when changed, publish a message. The Angular App would have to subscribe to the message channel, and update when a certain message is received.